# How to get vnode from DOM element in Vue 3.0?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

As in topic. How I can achieve getting vnode just by accessing DOM by `document.getElementById(id)` ?

Comment: You cant in production, in dev you can use __vueParentComponent.ctx but it's just to debug

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a good idea to map dom to virtual dom. But if you know what you are doing then go ahead. You can scan through virtual dom from root and check where each vnode is mounted to find one you are interested of.

There is some [info](https://vuejs-course.com/blog/diving-into-the-virtual-dom) about virtual dom scanning. Author of this article matching component types, but you can match `vnode.el`.